# android Dialog Gravity

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm trying to make a guide for my app.

i create a dialog that appear after 500ms and show the layout that have a image-view.

all thing is good Except Gravity.

i need to dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); but in app, not apply this code.

---

```
   void temp_help()
  {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread()
        {
           @Override
           public void run(){
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(personal_view_MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_temp_help);
                dialog.setTitle("  راهنما  "); 

                dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);



                dialog.show();

                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imghelp_view);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_temp_help2);
                    }
                });
           }
      }, 500);
        preferences.set_url("main_temp_help", "visited");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my method:

I had to run my app in multi-size and dialog. Should be full screen, I can't have a specified size for my image - so , I used from `FrameLayout` in `match_parent mode` that make my image(Dialog) full screen.

**Code below:**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/my-image-in-any-size"
    android:alpha=".87">
</FrameLayout>
```